# 0-reputation users

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

Go over [here](//stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all), on the last few pages, to find some users who, in fact, have **0 reputation points** (and yes, I'm on the "reputation" tab, with the "all" filter).

I wonder if it is a problem, because [your reputation can never drop below 1](/help/whats-reputation) (see bottom).

## Update Information

- <s>This might be a result of hacking or breaking the system, or a bug.</s>
- Those users do not have a network profile.
- The problem is fixed now, and those users were not hackers or anything. They were just Careers profiles that didn't have a SO account. Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Interesting. They also don't have a network profile, e.g. http://stackexchange.com/users/9369350/user9369350

Comment: @Glorfindel Can you please provide a link to the SO account? Yes, I can confirm there is no Network Profile. But, please, do not be confused; just changing the URL from `stackoverflow.com` to `stackexchange.com` is plain wrong.

Comment: All of those 0 rep user start here: http://stackoverflow.com/users?page=161408&tab=reputation&filter=all

Comment: Link may change due to new users being added.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος that's the link on [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6953208/user9369350).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This has to do with the rollout of the Developer Story. These users had a Careers profile but not a SO profile, so we created a profile for them.

The `0` reputation was an oversight and should be fixed now.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the problem! Also, what is Developer Story?

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος There isn't any formal announcement yet, but you can take a look at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/developer-story?sort=votes for some info.