# 10x spike in new users on October 10?

Tags: discussion, statistics

Browsing [sostats](http://sostats.github.io/) and saw this interesting chart:

[image: spike]

As you can see, new users normally stay at about 5,000 but then appear to jump to past 50,000 on October 10.

Was this a real spike or just an error in sostats' data? If it is real, what was the cause?

Comment: I'm not noticing anything out of the ordinary in the actual site's analytics dump.  I'm willing to bet that this third-party tool has a bug or two in it.

Comment: Me thinks that is when the developer story went live and they had to fill in all the empty users.

Comment: @NathanOliver:  This isn't an official source, though.

Comment: For everyone here that want to make wild guesses at what's going on: honestly, that's an obelisk amongst flatlands.  I don't know where this site gets its data or how it aggregates it, but my gut feeling is that they've got a bug on their hands.

Comment: @Makoto It is not a wild guess.  I remembered [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336034/0-reputation-users#comment403267_336034)

Comment: @Makoto [They use the SE API](http://stackapps.com/questions/6991/sostats-stack-overflow-live-statistics); but, yes, seems likely it's a bug.

Comment: Right - the API had a data bug, so the application needs to re-import that data to get back to normality.

Comment: @Makoto the api doesn't have such bug, there is a perfectly reasonable reason for this event: SE created a bunch of users that didn't have profiles.

Comment: @Braiam: ...which were picked up by this tool, which pulls its data from the API.  Now that the issue has been corrected, the API wouldn't have this erroneous data anymore, hence the maintainer needs to backfill this data in.

Comment: Come on @Makoto, use Occams razor. What would SE fixed? The users were actually created, the data is accurate, the app is simply reporting the data it has. There isn't a "bug", just a one off event!

Comment: So we have a classic interpretation error: The need for information is 'human new users' however the implementation is new profiles, which includes bot generated.

Comment: I find the clear trend of weekday vs weekday usage fascinating. Do _that_ many people really manage a complete cutoff from the programming world when Friday closes up? I'm jealous!

Answer (score 89, accepted):

> [This has to do with the rollout of the Developer Story. These users had a Careers profile but not a SO profile, so **we created a profile for them.**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/336036/792066)

It fits the timing, October 10.

Comment: I always love it when websites create a profile for me without asking.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the creator of [sostats](https://stackapps.com/questions/6991/sostats-stack-overflow-live-statistics). This number surprised me too but it's not a bug. The Stack Exchange API still returns over 50,000 new users created that day. You can try it yourself:

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users?site=stackoverflow&filter=total&fromdate=1476144000&todate=1476230399

My reasoning is the same as already noted - [launch of Developer Story](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/10/bye-bye-bullets-the-stack-overflow-developer-story-is-the-new-technical-resume/).